# How to read data from mongoDB to spark with a specific query

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am getting data from mongodb using the query,

db.objects.find({ _key: { $in: ["user:130"] } }, { _id: 0, uid: 1, username: 1 }).pretty();

now i need to get the same data in spark.

```
val readConf = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> host, "database" -> "nodebb", "collection" -> "objects"))

val data = spark.read.mongo(readConf)
```

This is giving complete data from mongodb.

How can i apply that query too...?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want for example just to filter some records you can use .filter on your df.

If you want to use sql queries on your data loaded from Mongo you can create temp view from your df and then query with spark.sql

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
some_fruit = spark.sql("SELECT type, qty FROM temp WHERE type LIKE '%e%'")
some_fruit.show()
```

More details in documentation: [MongoDB spark connector docu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/master/python/filters-and-sql/)